# Creating templates in Cloudstack

Tags: xen, apache-cloudstack

I am trying to get a cloudstack environment up and going. I have managed to get a server up, and it is pointed to my XenServer to manage. I have been able to create a couple of instances as well. In those instances, I have added some software, and gone through the initial install, and would like to make that my baseline. However, the screenshot below shows what I can see in the Templates section. When I click on Register template, I have no options for being able to make a template from a Volume or a snapshot of the instances I have created.

Am I doing something wrong here?

[image: CloudStack template screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [Create Template](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-administration/en/4.8/templates.html#creating-a-template-from-an-existing-virtual-machine)

*Create Template* starts from an existing volume.  In contrast, *Register Template* requires you to upload a volume into CloudStack.

Comment: Where is the "Create Template" button or whatever? If you notice in that screenshot in the behind-window, there is nowhere that says Create Template

Comment: It's under the Volume tab.  Select the volume you will make a template from.  It's under the window that appears.  I will try to get a screen shot up today.

Comment: Oh I just finally found it. I must have been blind before, I could have swore it wasn't there. I also had to stop the VM to make it happen.

Comment: Hi  can you please answer this Question of mine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877953/calling-cloud-stack-with-parameters

Comment: The link is broken, this is the [updated and working one](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-administration/en/4.8/templates.html#creating-a-template-from-an-existing-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

If you want create template of a vm then you will have to stop the vm and then you will have find the root volume of that vm ,you can in two way .First click on instances ,then click that particular instance ,then click on view volumes ,then select the volume whose name is starting with ROOt ,select fourth icon which is for template creation.Then fill the form and submit. Second one is go dashboard ,select storage then find the root volume which is having you vm name in vm display name cloumn ,select that root volume ,the click on fourth icon which is to create template.Fill the form and submit it.